# What is the missing number in the box

Tags: pattern, number-property

I found some online number puzzle as below:

[image]

My guess was 436 (go up by 118 again, as the left & right go up by 1) but apparently it was incorrect. I cannot see any other patterns, any ideas?

Comment: It'd be better if you also add the site where you've found it.

Comment: @Ak19 it was in a online chat messenger app, not sure where this puzzle came from, can't find it on google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One plausible answer is

> 476 because it's the left-hand number cubed minus the right-hand number squared.

But puzzles of this type always have multiple plausible answers, especially when there are only two examples given with answers, as in this case. Your answer, 436, is just as good as mine, in my opinion.

Comment: Nice stuff, the chat said it was correct, would've never thought of this.